# C# - Get StringComparer rules for all cultures

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison

I don't need to compare strings, I need to retrieve rules, that `StringComparer` uses for each culture to use them somewhere else.

Basically I need to get characters order for each culture.

I understand that it's not really C# related, because I need the data, not to make some code work. But since C# has `System.Globalization` it should have all data I need somewhere.

Comment: `var comparer = StringComparer.Create(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU"), false);` put actual culture instead of russian `"ru-RU"`

Comment: Rules are complex, for instance in Russian Culture `е` and `ё` are not distinguished when sorting; see for detail https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order